# Create object from list using stream/map java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects. I would like to create individual objects from this list with a method and not calling always: personList.get(0), personList.get(1), etc. The object name should be the Person name from the list element.

```
List<Person> personList = ...;
```

I'd like to iterate over the personList and create new objects by name for each object from the list.

Person class contains name attribute with a getter.

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to return a list of Person where the persons object have only name! or what exactly?

Comment: your question is not very clear. Can you mention a sample list input and the sample expected output? What do you mean by "it works case by case"? what is not working in the above case?

Comment: I updated the description, and remove the misleading code. Hope it is clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just stream the list and invoke the `map` operation as follows:

```
personList.stream()
          .map(x -> new T(x.getName()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `T` is the new type of elements you want to create e.g. `Student`, `Person`, `Employee` etc..

Comment: but the collect is collecting to a list. My main point is to go through the list and get every elements as a new Person object. Or did I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: @arena Which is exactly what the code is doing. Going through all the elements and constructing new objects with the people names. If you don’t collect the new elements to a list then where will you store the new objects constructed ?

Comment: Make sense! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple forEach loop:

```
personList.forEach(p -> {
  T newObject = new T(p.getName());
  // Do what you need to do with each new object
});
```

If you are trying to do something more complicated, then Aonminè's answer is probably what you really need.